# Avoid Edge Label Overlap Cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am writing a web app using Cytoscape. I often encounter label overlap, which could be easily solved by translating the label along the edge. Something like this:

[image]

Is this possible to automate? Can I somehow obtain the bounding boxes of the labels and set the position of the label along the edge, i.e., the distance to the nodes?

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered (by the lead developer of cytoscape.js himself). 

1: Adjust the relative sizes of your labels in your stylesheet. 2: Adjust your layout so that your nodes are spread farther apart. 3: Use short labels; you can show long text elsewhere, like in a tooltip.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am aware of this but these workarounds don't work for me.